# How to execute AJAX while loading a table

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm crating a table with a foreach for a PHP variable and I want every time the foreach cycle executes the AJAX gets loaded. There's my code:

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)
    <tr>
        <td> <img alt="Image placeholder" src="{{$theme->themeimg}}" width="30" height="30"> {{$theme->name}} </td>
        <td> <input name='nCertificates' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id='nCertificates' disabled> </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach




 function getThemeData(id) {

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/admin/themes/ntests/'+id,
          data: {'_token': $("input[name='_token']").val()},
          success: function (data) {

              console.log(data);

              $('#nCertificates').attr('placeholder', data).val(data);

          }
      });

  }
```

Comment: What's the issue/error you are facing

Comment: I think you need `<tr onload="getThemeData(id)">`, but this is wrong. you have to specify what is the issue, so we can answer

Comment: @Donkarnash. The AJAX isn't being loaded when the foreach is executed.

Comment: @davidsi02 please explain why you want to load ajax in php loop

Comment: _Small Point_ You are setting a static `id` attribute in a loop. Element id's should be unique on the page

Comment: @RobinSingh. I've tried already but it don't work.

Comment: "*The AJAX isn't being loaded when the foreach is executed.*" - doing ajax calls in a loop is never a good idea - think of alternate way to get the data by keeping the ajax calls to a minimum

Comment: Make the id on input unique for each iteration in the loop  - something like **id=$theme->name' . -nCertificates'**

Comment: What is the reasoning behind using AJAX in a server-side environment? You should fetch all the data you need and insert it directly into the table.